# ggplot2::geom_smooth fails with method=gamlss::gamlss, with warning about different number of rows: 80, 81

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, gamma-distribution, gamlss

I have decades of daily rainfall data, which are mostly zeroes (dry days). The Zero-Adjusted Gamma Distribution (`ZAGA`) fits the data relatively well. I'd like to plot the relationship between rainfall and a continuous variable, using `ggplot2::geom_smooth()`, with `gamlss::gamlss(family=ZAGA())`. However, when I try to do so, I get the following warning and the plot is empty:

`` Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: arguments imply differing number of rows: 80, 81 ``

The numbers of rows are `80, 81` for a largely number of different data (sub)sets that I've tried.

A MWE where this occurs:

```
library(gamlss)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

in_df <- tibble(x = c(0.1, 3.1, 3, 0.5, 2, 0.2, 2.9, 1.2, 1, 0.2),
                y = c(0, 2, 0, 0.2, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0))

gamlss_fit <- gamlss(data = in_df, formula = y ~ x)    # works fine

ggplot(in_df) + 
    geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = y), method = "gam", formula = y ~ x)  # "works" as well

ggplot(in_df) + 
    geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = y), method = gamlss::gamlss, formula= y ~ x, se = F)  # gives warning
```

Does this mean that `gamlss` is not supported with `geom_smooth`/`stat_smooth`? I found this [forum post](https://groups.google.com/g/ggplot2/c/1CCPNCq7QwM) that suggests a workaround, but I was hoping to be able to use geom_smooth to also display a confidence interval on the plot and to do the fitting by grouping or faceting variable.

Alternatively, is there a distribution one could use with `method = "gam"` or another fitting function that would be appropriate for these data? I can't seem to find a zero-inflated continuous distribution (or mixed distribution) for this purpose.

Comment: based on the rdocumentation of geom_smooth, you want to use an external function for your method so the code should be ```method = "gamlss::gamlss" ```. You need to tell the geom_smooth from which package the function for your method should come from. It doesn't check outside ggplot on it's on. ``` "gam" ``` is an argument within ggplot, ``` "gamlss" ``` is not.

Comment: Thank you @Omniswitcher, I've changed the call in the example above. The outcome is not changed.